# Вывод общего времени трека NAudio C#

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, wav, naudio

Необходимо выводить время треков. Получается сделать, если например только mp3. Но в плейлисте могут быть и другие форматы, например WAV и Vorbis. Как можно реализовать автоматическое переключение между типами для вывода времени для любых из двух типов файлов.
Сейчас сделал следующим образом:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var file in GetFileInfo())
            {
                Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file.FullName);
                WaveFileReader s; //??

                TimeSpan duration = reader.TotalTime;
                Console.WriteLine(duration);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IList<FileInfo> GetFileInfo()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directories = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\TestAudio");
        var extensions = new string[] { "*.mp3", "*.mp4", "*.wav", "*.wma", "*.ogg", "*.spx" };
        var files = extensions.SelectMany(ext => directories.GetFiles(ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));

        return files.ToList();
    }
```

Когда доходит до WAV файлов соответственно выводит исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте AudioFileReader:

```
AudioFileReader reader = new AudioFileReader(path);
```

Он должен уметь выводить длину для всех поддерживаемых типов файлов (это включает WAV и MP3, но не OGG Vorbis, если только для него не установлен кодек).

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое! Единственно, треки с битрейдом ниже 100 кб/с кидают исключение.